# Give access to only two (/home, /inbox) page for a particular user with specific role in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I want to give only two page (/home, /inbox) access to my user with role "Vendor", if user tries to access other pages than it will automatically redirect to "/inbox" page, I put the below code to achieve the functionality but after adding this to function.php, site again n again redirect and finally dies with message "Page isn't properly redirected". please suggest what is wrong with my tried code or any other solution.

```
function vendor_redirect() {
   global $post;
   if(current_user_can('Vendor') && !in_array($post->slug,array("home","inbox"))) {
      wp_safe_redirect('/inbox');
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'vendor_redirect');
```

Comment: First of all you should put an "exit" after wp_safe_redirect() - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect

Comment: If it's constantly looping, then your second if conditional must always be true. `in_array` is case sensitive, are you sure the slug isn't Inbox?

Comment: Thanks of reply guys but the main issue the way I tried to get the page slug, the correct way to get the slug is "$post->post_name" also I put exit after wp_safe_redirect as well because codex suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue the way I tried to get the page slug, the correct way to get the slug is "$post->post_name". also I put exit after wp_safe_redirect as well because codex suggest that:

```
function vendor_redirect() {
   global $post;
   if(current_user_can('Vendor') && !in_array($post->post_name,array("home","inbox"))) {
      wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink(get_page_by_path( 'inbox' )));
      exit;
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'vendor_redirect');
```